# Server with 4GB RAM - amount of memory to set the memory_limit in PHP for this server?

Tags: php, memory-limit

I have a dedicated cloud server with 4GB of RAM and 4 Cores 1.2GHz.

I have an extremely robust system running and would like to know the amount of memory to set the memory_limit in PHP 5.5?

Comment: This is not duplicate. Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Benchmark your specific application and go from there.**

Without knowing what your application is or does it's really difficult to suggest a limit that would suit it. You may find giving other parts of your app server (os, httpd, db) more memory will give you a bigger performance boost than simply upping the limit PHP can use.

**This particularly applies for databases**, for many applications this is the bottleneck.

So either [set it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits) quite high, or turn the limit off entirely and look at benchmarking its use over periods of high (real or [simulated](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php)) use and see then what you think it really needs, and add a 10-15% buffer on top of that.

No suggestion from any of us will beat actively monitoring its performance and adjusting as your application and users change.